# How to encode an acess token into an API request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, oauth, encode, access-token

I have the access_token in Javascript. I am working with the Stripe API and want to make a request like this:

```
  function apiReq() {
    if(localStorage.accessToken !== null){
      $.get( "https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance/history", {
        access_token: localStorage.accessToken, 
        count: 3
      }).done(function( data ) {
        alert(data);
      }).fail(function(response) {
         alert('failed' + response.responseText);
});
}
}
```

How do I encode the access_token so that the API can authorize the request?

PS. I am making the requests from Steroids.js/Phonegap so their isn't security issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean http basic auth, you can use [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXX");
  },
  // ...
```

Comment: Is this what it should look like? I'm not sure what to put in "Basic XXXXX"

`$.get({
      url: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance/history", 
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", localStorage.accessToken)
      }
    }
`